# Sql function - disregarding the decimal place in returning value

Tags: sql, function

Why is it that sql query will disregard the decimal place when using SUM function?
iv'e use CONVERT function but it doesn't return the right value.

example:

150.30 * 3 = 450.9

but on the result of my function it return

150.30 * 3 = 451 it round the decimal place.

how can i get the exact result of calculation...?

here's my sql function query

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetSubjectCost](@id INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL 
AS 
-- Returns the stock level for the product.
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret DECIMAL;

SELECT @ret = IIF([Name] = 'Tuition', CONVERT([DECIMAL](9,2),Cost) * CONVERT([DECIMAL](15,2),t1.SubjectUnit), CONVERT([DECIMAL](9,2),Cost))
    FROM [HCCDB].[dbo].[SubjectOfferedFee] AS t0
        INNER JOIN HCCDB.dbo.SubjectsOffered  AS t1
            ON t1.SubjectsOfferedID = t0.SubjectsOfferedID
            WHERE t0.SubjectOfferedFeeID = @id
IF (@ret IS NULL) 
SET @ret = 0;
RETURN CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), @ret);
END;
```

The query work but it did not return exact value. it disregard the decimal place.

purpose of this function is the add on column formula.

```
ALTER TABLE HCCDB.dbo.SubjectOfferedFee
ADD FinalCost AS CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2), dbo.fnGetSubjectCost(CONVERT(INT, [SubjectOfferedFeeID])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the declaration of `@ret`.

In SQL Server, the default scale for a decimal is 0 (see the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)).  So,

```
declare @ret decimal;
```

is equivalent to:

```
declare @ret decimal(18, 0);
```

Just be explicit about the precision and scale, something like:

```
declare @ret decimal(18, 2);
```

Comment: i use 2012, but i got the same result, no decimal place.

`DECLARE @ret DECIMAL(18,2);`

Comment: oh yes it work just adding precision and scale on DataType Return

`ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetSubjectCost](@id INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18, 2)`

no it work good.

Comment: @mardagz . . . Sorry about that.  I missed the declaration of the function itself.  As you point out, that also needs an explicit precision and scale.

Comment: its ok @Gordon Linoff with that it gives me an idea. :D thanks bro.